# Как преобразовать date-формат, взятый из БД в Javascript?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть формат даты в базе данных, (поле с date-форматом) например, **20-05-202**1 (5 мая 2021 года). Хочу этот формат  D-M_Y(D-день,M-месяц,Y-год --> ну это чисто я щас придумал такую надпись, к формату она отношения не имеет). Мне нужно ее преобразовать в вид **20 мая (21г.)**. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const foo = (dateStr, opt) => {
  let re = '(?<d>\\d{1,2}).(?<m>\\d{1,2}).(?<y>\\d{4})'; 
  if (opt instanceof RegExp) {     // имена групп: y - год; m - месяц; d - день
    re = opt; 
  } else {
    if ((typeof opt === 'string') && opt.length)  // разделитель (любая строка)
      re = re.replace('.', opt);
    re = new RegExp(re); 
  }
  const { d, m, y } = (re.exec(dateStr) || {}).groups || {}; 
  if (!d) return null; 
  const date = new Date(+y, m - 1, +d, 0, 0, 0); 
  if (!date) return null; 
  return date.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {
    day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: '2-digit', 
  }).replace(/(\d\d)\D+$/, '($1г.)'); 
}; 

console.log(foo('20-05-2021'));        // ➝ '20 мая (21г.)'
console.log(foo('5.2 2021'));          // ➝ '5 февраля (21г.)'
console.log(foo('12.10.2021', '-'));   // ➝ null
console.log(foo('12.10.2021', '.'));   // ➝ '12 октября (21г.)'
console.log(foo('210913', /(?<y>\d\d)(?<m>\d\d)(?<d>\d\d)/));   // ➝ '13 сентября (21г.)'
```

Comment: Именованные группы в регулярках поддерживаются не везде (см. caniuse) - поэтому, может потребоваться полифилл (средствами транспайлера, или библиотеки типа _regexp-polyfill_).